# How to provide arguments to IN Clause in HIve

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Is there any way to read arguments in **HIVEquery** which can substitute to an **IN** Clause. I have the below query with me.

```
Select count (*) from table where id in ('1','2','3','4','5').
```

Is there any way to supply the arguments to IN Clause from a text file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in_file: Put all ids into file, one id in a row.

```
Select count (*) from table where in_file(id, '/tmp/myfilename'); --local file
```

Also you can pass the list of values as a single parameter to the IN: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56963448/2700344

Also instead if IN you can do `left semi join` with a table containing these IDs, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41056870/2700344